# Android How to enable/disable ethernet from an application?

Tags: android, ethernet

How can i enable/disable the ethernet from my android app? There is no EthernetManager in SDK like WifiManager.

Comment: Did you get any solution for your question ?

Answer (score 2):

Android comes with `ifconfig` (configure arbitrary network and netmask, also to put the network up or down). and `dhcpcd` (obtain and use dynamic ip). Both commands work for me. I cannot find any GUI tools so far.

Unfortunately, this is currently only possible with the rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible in Android, sorry.